# How can I read 50kV using the built in ADC of a Teensy microcontroller?

Tags: power-electronics, adc, voltage-divider, high-voltage, teensy

Can I use the voltage divider like shown below for stepping down the voltage to 3.3V? Is there a better solution to digitise the voltage values?

[image]

Comment: No. Do it in two or three pass lowering the voltage ...

Comment: What's the voltage rating for each of the 1 Gohm resistors?

Comment: 20kV voltage rating of each resistor used

Comment: At first glance, I would multiply every resistors by 10. At least.

Comment: Is this 50kV DC or AC?

Comment: Check Teensy input impedance. If it is lower than 10 Mohm, you should buffer your sensed voltage before feeding it into the Teensy (using a FET opamp).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes in theory, but probably no in practice.

At 50 kV, creepage and voltage limits on the individual devices becomes critical.  Unless you are using special, high voltage resistors such as [these](https://www.ohmite.com/assets/docs/acl_arc2.pdf) or [these](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1491587.pdf), R1-R3 will fail under ~17 kV each.

Find the highest working voltage resistors that suits your budget, then determine the number required to meet your operating voltage, then select values to give the required division (respecting load impedance and power dissipation).

Implement as a long ladder to provide creepage protection.  For 50 kV you may well also need grading electrodes / [corona rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corona_ring) to provide corona protection.  Alternatively you might want to immerse the whole string in oil, with corona protection limited to the top connection point.

Finally, be very, very careful with the grounding connection at the bottom of your divider.  If that detaches, the whole string will float up, and depending on capacitances could give you a nasty surprise on contact (though max current should be limited).

Depending on your setup, electrostatic measurement or corona current measurement from needle electrodes may give you a better result.

Answer (score 5):

Besides the problems dealing with high voltages you will also need to take into account the impedance of the circuit following the divider, which will appear in parallel with the bottom of the divider. Using the values in your schematic, anything under 10 megohms is going to give you a significant error.

For example, suppose the ADC input impedance is 1M, that in parallel with 200k will give you
$$
\frac{1M\times200k}{1M+200k} = 166.666k
$$
and the voltage would be
$$
50kV\times\frac{166.666k}{3G+166.666k} = 2.777V
$$

So if you want accuracy you'll need to account for that, which could be done in software, by adding a high impedance input buffer before your ADC, or by adjusting the resistances in the divider.

Comment: On top of that, an ADC input is typically capacitive, and the larger the Thévenin resistance of the source, the longer you have to allow that capacitor to charge.

Answer (score 3):

As others have already said, yes, a resistor divider is essentially the way to do this. I work on extremely high voltage (>450kV) x-ray systems that use exactly this method for HV feedback.

However, very few people are actually qualified to build a safe HV measurement system without killing themselves.

I would suggest that you just buy a proper HV probe. The [CPS Model 250](https://www.cpshv.com/products/250.htm) is one example.

Please stay safe.

Comment: If his budget is in the teensy (~50$), I doubt he'd buy 700$ probe. But I agree with you!

Answer (score 0):

That circuit might work provided you add an operational amplifier configured as a unit gain buffer between Vout and the input of your ADC.

Ciao